# Kotlin - Issue with Elvis operator

Tags: kotlin, nullability, elvis-operator

Why the below code gives error? It should print "Bonjour" as output

```
 fun main()
{

    var a:String? = null
    var b:String? = "Hello"

    var result1 = a?:"Gracias"
    var result2 = b?:"Bonjour"
    println(result2)
}
```

Comment: `b` is `"Hello"`, so `b ?: "Bonjour"` will return `"Hello"`

Comment: Why did you think it should print "Bonjour"?

Comment: Because result variable would hold "Hello" when b is not null.. Hence printing result would print "Hello"??

Answer (score 1):

`b?:"Bonjour"` means, “if `b` is not null, then whatever `b` is, but if it’s null, then `"Bonjour"`. Since `b` is not null, it evaluates to what `b` is, which is `"Hello"`.

By the way, the term “error” in the programming world means the code will not compile, not that it’s giving you unexpected results when you run it.

Comment: "Error" could also mean a runtime exception, when used loosely.

Comment: @k314159, true although using it that way when discussing Java and Kotlin can be confusing because Error is a Throwable that is not an Exception. Errors are rarely ever encountered.